# How to exclude column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update

i have question here. How can I exclude one column from both inserted and deleted table in sql server 2008? I am currently using After update trigger.

Code is as below:

```
select * into #ins from inserted
select * into #del from deleted
```

I want to exclude some column from the 2 tables

Comment: What's the point in copying the data from the pseudo-tables into temp tables in the first place?

Comment: And there's no `*-except-some-columns` syntax - you *should* always be using explicit column lists rather than `select *` anyway, and if you want to exclude a column, an explicit column list is the only way forward.

Comment: Use column names instead of * in your second select

Answer (score 0):

You should state the column names instead of the '*'.

```
select col1, col2, ... , coln into #ins from inserted
```